# Vue.js фокус на элементе

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Подскажите как установить фокус на элементе? Я использую библиотеку `vue-single-select`. Есть вот такой селект

```
<div class="input-field col s12 m4">
    <vue-single-select
        v-model="mark"
        :options=this.markList
        :required="true"
        :max-results="20"
        ref="markList"
        placeholder="Выберите марку"/>
</div>
```

Необходимо, чтобы при открытии страницы каретка вставала в поле для поиска в селекте. Пробовал использовать `this.$refs['markList'].focus()`, но не помогает

Comment: как минимум нужно посмотреть какие элементы генерирует vue-single-select в DOM и уже среди них сориентироваться на каком из них фокус включать

Comment: @t0lik кажется понял. Спасибо, что навели на мысль. Просто JS для меня совсем не родная стихия.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение: `this.$refs['markList'].$refs['search'].focus()`